# How to pass a Hash to Grape API method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm having problems with the Grape gem and the parameters validation. 
The idea behind this is to create a complex entity using nested attributes through an API service.

I have a method to create a trip, trip have many destinations and i want to pass that destinations using a hash (using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` helper).

I have this grape restriction over the parameter:

```
requires :destinations, type: Hash
```

And I'm trying to send something like this:

```
{ destinations => [ 
  { destination: { name => 'dest1'} },
  { destination: { name => 'dest2'} }, 
  { destination: { name => 'dest3'} }
]}
```

In order to build something like the structure below inside the method and get the trip created:

```
{ trip: {
  name: 'Trip1', destinations_attributes: [
    { name: 'dest1' },
    { name: 'dest2' },
    { name: 'dest3' }
  ]
}}
```

I'm using POSTMAN chrome extension to call the API method.

Here's a screen capture: [image]

If someone can help me i would be very grateful.

Comment: During editing of your post I discovered you missed one curly bracket (after destination3,) making your hash an invalid structure. Was this a cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of what you are trying to send, you need to change the Grape restriction, because `destinations` is an `Array`, not a `Hash`:

```
requires :destinations, type: Array
```

You don't need the "destination" hash when sending the request:

```
{ destinations => [ 
  { name => 'dest1', other_attribute: 'value', etc... },
  { name => 'dest2', other_attribute: 'value', etc... }, 
  { name => 'dest3', other_attribute: 'value', etc... }
]}
```

This creates an Array of hashes.

In order to send this through POSTMAN, you'll need to modify that `destinations` param your sending and add multiple lines in POSTMAN. Something like:

```
destinations[][name]                'dest1'
destinations[][other_attribute]     'value1'
destinations[][name]                'dest2'
destinations[][other_attribute]     'value2'
destinations[][name]                'dest3'
destinations[][other_attribute]     'value3'
```

Hope this answers your questions. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.